# Need help on a method

Tags: c#, string, methods, input, output

i just started learning c# and i am trying to make a console application that will read a text file and show it on the command prompt. I am also trying to make the method that reads the text file in a separate dll because i plan to expand my program later on and try to make a sort of text based game engine. anyway, here is my code in my dll:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace EngineFeatures
{
    public class txtedit
    {

        public string Write_txt(string textin, out String output)
        {
            try
            {
                 using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(textin))
                {


                    String line = sr.ReadToEnd();
                    output = line;
                    return output;
                }

            }
             catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The file could not be read:");
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

like i am a beginner, i literally just started 3 days ago. anyway what i want to do is be able to call the function EngineFeatures.txtedit.Write_txt("TXT/test.txt"); in the application itself and have it return a string, but i am still a bit confused and i also get an error saying "EngineFeatures.txtedit.Write_txt(string, out string)': not all code paths return a value."
what am i doing wrong?

Comment: The error message should be clear; if an exception occurs in your `try` block, it won't return anything since you don't have another return statement anywhere else.

Comment: Your question title does not really explain what your question is. You should give a more descriptive title.

Answer (score 6):

There is nothing returned from your method in case of exception. Add some default value to return or throw (another) exception to caller:

```
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("The file could not be read:");
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    return null; 
    // or: return String.Empty
    // or: throw new GameLoadException("Cannot read game file", e);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are couple of things in your code, First you are passing a variable with `out` keyword and then returning the same variable. You can get rid of the `out` in the parameter list and simply return the `output` in try block, but in case of exception you should also return some value probably `null` like:

**EDIT:** You can get rid of the `output` parameter completely and just return the line. *(Thanks to @Jim)*

```
public string Write_txt(string textin)
{
    try
    {
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(textin))
        {
            String line = sr.ReadToEnd();
            return line;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The file could not be read:");
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Good answer, but in your example you could go even further and just get rid of the second parameter "output", and just return sr.ReadToEnd();

Comment: @jim, yeah but I actually wanted to convey that something should be returned from both try and catch block. But you right, I am going to modify it.

Comment: Instead of returning from both try and catch blocks, I often declare the object to be returned outside the try block, and return it after the end of the catch.  So I'd have string output = string.Empty; just before the try.  Then I'd set output = sr.ReadToEnd(); from within the try, and then just after the catch I'd return output;  Inside the catch you can either set output to null, or set it to string.empty, or throw an new exception, whatever.  Returning from outside the try/catch though means you only need one return statement, and you don't need a separate one for every catch.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class txtedit
{

    public string Write_txt(string textin, out String output)
    {
        output = "";

        try
        {
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(textin))
            {


                String line = sr.ReadToEnd();
                output = line;
                return output;
            }


        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The file could not be read:");
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
        return output;

    }
```